# WordPress Fatal Error Class 'wpforge_walker' not found line 317

Tags: wordpress

I'm receiving the following error on my WordPress website:

> Fatal error: Class 'wpforge_walker' not found in
>   /home/content/25/11572025/html/site/wp-content/themes/wp-starter/content-nav.php
>   on line 317

On my FTP File Manager, line 317 on "content-nav.php" shows the following:

```
'walker' => new wpforge_walker( array(
```

After reading on this issue other forums mentioned how removing the parenthesis might solve the problem. Accordingly, this is how I saved the "content-nav.php" file:

```
'walker' => new wpforge_walker
```

After refreshing my website, it is showing the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''in_top_bar''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in
>   /home/content/25/11572025/html/site/wp-content/themes/wp-starter/content-nav.php
>   on line 319

I went back to my FTP File Manager and put back the "( array(" into the "content-nav.php" file and now I'm back to my initial problem.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour].

Regarding your question: It is hard to debug your code without all the information. At least consider giving us the complete definition of 'walker'... instead of just the first line (It is obviously spanning multiple lines).

Comment: Not sure what "walker" or "wpforge_walker" is, but let me know what other information you need and I will definitely provide it. Here is the code for "content-nav.php":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Theme wp-starter, can you share any more info about it, developer, website, etc.?

Share a bigger chunk of code from content-nav.php, for example rows 300 till 350. Make sure you include the complete block of code.

Removing `( array(` will result in another error. This is normal because it will completely break the function.

**Some info about the error.**
The code wants to load the class `wpforge_walker`, but it isn't available. Something went wrong with including the file that contains that particular class.

In the error log, do you see another returning log (notice or something else) before the fatal error? I'm looking for an `include_once()` / `No such file or directory` error, or something like that.

Another option is to re-upload ALL theme files, maybe an update or something else did not complete correctly. You can overwrite all theme files savely.
***Edit: re-upload all theme files fixed the problem.***

**Disable theme to get WP admin access.**
Using FTP or a hosting filemanager you can rename the theme folder, example 'wp-starter-off'.
WP will then deactivate the theme and you can access WP again.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Here's line 303 to 341:

<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location' => 'primary',
'container' => false,
'depth' => 0,
'items_wrap' => '<ul class="left">%3$s</ul>',
'fallback_cb' => '', // workaround to show a message to set up a menu
'walker' => new wpforge_walker( array(
'in_top_bar' => true,
'item_type' => 'li',
'menu_type' => 'main-menu'
) ),
) );
?>
</section>
<section class="top-bar-section right show-for-large-up">
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'social_menu' ); ?>
</section>
</nav>
</div><!-- contain-to-grid sticky -->
</div><!-- .row -->

Comment: OK, the function add's a new wp_nav_menu and uses a custom walker instance. The Class that handles this, is not loaded correctly. Did you try / check my other suggestions? It appears the problem is not in the content-nav.php file but somewhere else. Did you check the error log for other notices etc? P.s. it's better to use/edit your orginal question to add additional info.

Comment: Yes, I reloaded all of the theme files and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! If you can set my answer as the correct one, that would be great also ^^.